# Button Content as their Name

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, wpf-controls

My Question is purely related to XAML and not code behind.

Can a WPF Button Content be same as its Name.

One way of doing it is like

```
<Button Name="button1" Content="button1">
```

But i have 250 such buttons and changing both button name and content is like changing at 500 places. so is there a way where i have to change only the button name and content reflects that value.

```
<Button Name = "button1" Content ={??????}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx):

```xml
Content="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

*(Read the reference, data-binding is an integral part of [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx))*